# .htaccess redirect is resulting in a 404 how can i fix this

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically i want my index.php to be College-recruiting-videos so i looked it up on stackoverflow and found this rewrite rule

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^index.php College-recruiting-videos [R=301]
```

So i put that in my htaccess and saved it but now my index.php 404's why?

http://primetimehighlights.com/college-recruiting-videos

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this.

```
RewriteRule ^College-recruiting-videos$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I thought the first rule is what it looks for? So wouldn't that replace College-recruiting-video with Index.php I'm trying to replace index.php with College-recruiting-video..

Comment: i could easily be wrong though cause i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html